# Streaming video with FFmpeg through pipe causes partial file offset error and moov atom not found

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video, streaming

I'm trying to stream a video from firebase cloud storage through ffmpeg then to the HTML video player, using a very basic example with the range header worked fine and was exactly what I was trying to do, **but now when I'm trying to pipe the stream from firebase then through ffmpeg then to the browser it works fine for just first couple of requests (First 10 seconds) but after that It faced these issues:**

- Unable to get the actual time of the video on the browser (Constantly changing as if it doesn't know metadata)
- On the server it fails to continue streaming to the request with the following:

```
[NULL @ 000001d8c239e140] Invalid NAL unit size (110356 > 45446).
[NULL @ 000001d8c239e140] missing picture in access unit with size 45450
pipe:0: corrupt input packet in stream 0
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001d8c238c7c0] stream 0, offset 0x103fcf: partial file
```

and then this error as well:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001dc9590c7c0] moov atom not found
pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input
```

### Using nodejs and running Ffmpeg V 5.0.1 on serverless env:

```
  const filePath = `sample.mp4` ||  req.query.path;

    // Create a read stream from the video file
    const videoFile = bucket.file(filePath);

    const range = req.headers.range;

    if(!range){
      return res.status(500).json({mes: 'Not Found'});
    }

      // Get the file size for the 'Content-Length' header
      const [metadata] = await videoFile.getMetadata();
      const videoSize = metadata.size;

      const CHUNK_SIZE = 1000000; // 1MB

      const start = Number(range.replace(/\D/g, ""));
      const end = Math.min(start + CHUNK_SIZE, videoSize - 1);
    
      // Create headers
      const contentLength = end - start + 1;
      const headers = {
        "Content-Range": `bytes ${start}-${end}/${videoSize}`,
        "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
        "Content-Length": contentLength,
        "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
        // 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
      };
    
      // HTTP Status 206 for Partial Content
      res.writeHead(206, headers);
    
      // create video read stream for this particular chunk
      const inputStream = videoFile.createReadStream({ start, end });

     const ffmpeg = spawn(pathToFfmpeg, [
        // '-re', '-y',  
        '-f', 'mp4',  
        '-i', 'pipe:0', // read input from standard input (pipe)
        '-c:v', 'copy', // copy video codec
        '-c:a', 'copy', // copy audio codec
        '-map_metadata', '0',
        `-movflags`, `frag_keyframe+empty_moov+faststart+default_base_moof`,
        '-f', 'mp4', // output format
        'pipe:1',
       // write output to standard output (pipe)
      ], {
        stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'inherit']
      });

      inputStream.pipe(ffmpeg.stdin);

      ffmpeg.stdout.pipe(res);
```

**Note that this version is trimmed I do have a lot of log code and error handling of course, and basically again what's happening is that for the first request it is working fine but then if the player requests a part like minute 5 for example it gives the errors I mentioned above:**

### What I have tried:

- At first I tried adjusting the ffmpeg parameters with the following to try and fix the moov atom error but it still presisted:

```
    -map_metadata', '0',
    `-movflags`, `frag_keyframe+empty_moov+faststart+default_base_moof`
```

- I have also tried to stream to file then through pipe but that also gave the same errors.

Finally after googling for about day and a half trying out tens of solutions nothing worked, now **I'm stuck at this error where I'm not able to process a specific fragment of a video through ffmpeg, is that even possible or am I doing something wrong?**

### Why am I even streaming through ffmpeg?

I am indeed of course going to add filters to the video and a dynamic watermark text for every request **that's why I need to use ffmpeg through stream not directly through a file as the video filters will change on demand according to every user**

Comment: @user2305193 Yes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75749608/adding-ffmpeg-layer-to-hls-streaming-causes-video-playback-issues